# jQuery Mobile panels display on initial load with slower devices before page fully loads

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, webview

I have noticed with a webview app I created that with slower devices the jQuery mobile panels I have created within my site will display briefly at the bottom of the body when the webview first loads, but then disappears when fully loaded.

I was wondering if there was a way with jQuery mobile to prevent that.

If there is no way to do it within jQuery mobile my idea is to assign the panel initially with a `display: none`

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="panel" id="this_panel" data-display="overlay" style="display: none">
```

And then with jQuery apply a `display: block` when the button used to display the panel is clicked like

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '#panel_button', function() {
    $('#this_panel').show();
})
```

**UPDATE**

So I think I found a pretty good solution to keep it as clean as possible while the page is loading. Since the Panels work off of `<li>` lists. When the page initially loads and its a slower device you see the panel html initially at the bottom of the page briefly before the CSS applies to it which then hides it.

What I did was put the panel container like `<div data-role="panel" id="tickets_cog_panel" data-display="overlay"></div>`, but then with jQuery I load the html through `$('#tickets_cog_panel').html('html here')`. Since jQuery has to wait to load until the content is fully loaded it loads much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** I was wondering if there was a way with jQuery mobile to prevent that?

**A:** Unfortunately not, jQuery Mobile is notorious for its bugs and you will probably never see them fixed (we are talking about dead framework).

The usual answer is simple, implement a splash screen.

Hide it on [mobileinit](https://api.jquerymobile.com/mobileinit/) event.

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {


});
```

If you are still facing even with mobileinit event you should use [pageshow](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/) event instead.

Use Cordova splash screen instead.

Another approach is to hide it as you previously stated and enable it again on mobileinit or pageinit event.